# extracting terms from query in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I am trying to extract terms from user-specified queries using Lucene 3.0.3. My code is shown below:

```
protected Set<Term> getTerms(IndexSearcher searcher, Analyzer analyzer, String field, String queryString, boolean countOnly) {
    Set<Term> results = null;
    try {
        logger.trace( "Creating parser and analyzer" );
        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, field, analyzer );
        logger.trace( "Constructing query" );
        Query query = qp.parse(queryString);
        query.rewrite(searcher.getIndexReader());
        logger.trace( "Evaluating query: [" + query.toString() + "]");
        terms = new HashSet<Term>();
        query.extractTerms( terms );
    } catch(UnsupportedOperationException uoex) {
        logger.error("Error parsing query: " + e.getMessage() );
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        logger.error( "Error parsing query: " + e.getMessage() );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error( "IO Exception in processing query", e);
    }
    return terms;
}
```

This works fine unless there is (for example) a question mark in the query text. If that happens, the `query.extractTerms(terms);` line throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`. This was happening before I added the `query.rewrite()` call which was supposed to prevent this error. Unfortunately, the error still occurs. Interestingly, the query is parsed and executed (in a different method) just fine; it's just the `extractTerms()` call that fails.

What should I try next?

Gene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you discard the result of query.rewrite